# Como implementar um mapa que mostra localização em tempo real - com deslocamento?

Tags: mapas, realtime-database

Esse é o cenário:

Por exemplo,  se eu quisesse mostrar todas as moradias dos usuários de uma cidade (os que estiverem cadastrados no sistema)  bastaria fazer uma requisição no banco de dados antes que a página seja carregada, recuperar as coordenadas geográficas que foram previamente fornecida pelos usuários durante o processo de inscrição, e enviar para o javascript quando ele estiver usando a [API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) para instanciar o mapa. É assim que eu faço atualmente com os meus projetos.

A minha minha dúvida seria como mostrar em tempo real o deslocamento de um usuário qualquer sobre esse mesmo mapa anteriormente criado? Como implementar essa funcionalidade?

Comment: você precisa atualizar a posição do usuário (supondo que você queira rastrear via gps o celular, por exemplo) e redesenhar os pontos no mapa. Eu indico esse procedimento porque você não precisa controlar uma a um qual marcador se movimentou a cada x segundos (tempo que o mapa é atualizado.

Comment: exato, seria via gps do celular para enviar as coordenadas do ponto. De preferencia seria a cada segundo. E eu gostaria de ver no mapa todos os usu[arios cadastrados se locomovendo ao mesmo tempo. [E para um estudo de deslocamento em massa, por isso precisa de se visualizar todos os usuarios em tempo real. Mas como seria implementacao? Atualizar o mapa a cada segundo ou existe  alguma funcao para isso?

Comment: então, dei uma pesquisada se tem algum mecanismo de atualização automática mas não encontrei.. eu já implementei isso e foi na mão mesmo.. `window.setTimeout("AtualizarTela()", 30000);` onde meu método de atualização do mapa era chamado a cada 30 segundos (esse método vai na base pegar os dados das posições atualizadas e recarrega o mapa)

Comment: Oi @rLinhares eu ja trabalhei com a API do google map. O mais dinâmico que eu consegui fazer foi criar uma página em php que pega as informações numa base de dados e  cria dinamicamente o código javascript (tem Outras Maneira). Dessa maneira quando o mapa é criado na tela ele já vai conter as últimas informações dos meus pontos de interesse. Então essa página era recarregada a cada minuto. Ou seja, a cada minuto o mapa era recriado. Eu estava trabalhando com informaçoes (que poderiam mudar) mas de um estabelecimento fixo. As coordenadas do meu ponto de interesse não mudam. Agora é o contrário

Comment: Continuando, se eu quisesse ver em tempo real  o deslocamento de uma pessoa que possui um celular enviando as coordenadas geográficas para o sistema a cada segundo, a sua proposta seria refazer o refresh da página a cada segundo?

Comment: a ideia é a mesma que você trabalhou, recarregar os pontos no mapa a cada x segundos. A diferença é que você precisa atualizar esses pontos de acordo com a posição atual do cara que está se movendo.

Comment: ok, entao a ideia seria deletar todos os pontos e criar novamente a cada segundo e n'ao recriar o mapa novamente

Comment: isso.. dessa forma você não "gasta" as requisições do maps e nem perde tempo recriando o mapa

Answer (score 1):

Achei a solução para essa aplicação.
Um ponto (ou um objeto qualquer - um marcador) que se desloca no googleMaps usando a API.

Um deslocamento será uma sequência de pontos (posições) que irá aparecer no mapa de forma sucessiva - um após o outro.

```
      var markers = [];  
      var mapObject;
      var z=0;
      var myLatLngA = [];   

      function setMapOnAll(map) {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          markers[i].setMap(map);
        }        
      }

      setInterval(function() {            
        setMapOnAll(null);//Limpa qualquer ponto que estejam no mapa
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({//Cria o objeto marker
          position: myLatLngA[z],//Usando a próxima posição de uma array de
                                 //posições. Essa array pode ser criada a
                                 //partir de dados provenientes de um um
                                 //banco de dados como firebase por exemplo
          map: mapObject         
        });
        markers.push(marker);    //guarda o objeto marker numa array
        marker.setMap(mapObject);//Plota o marcador no mapa
        z++; 
      }, 1000);
```